# Vue JS | "Управление снегом"

Tags: vue.js

Сложилась забавная ситуация: Не могу управлять снегом.

Есть модуль `vue-snowf`.

```
<Snowf
       :amount=snow.amount
       :size=snow.size
       :speed=snow.speed
       :wind=snow.wind
       :opacity=snow.opacity
       :swing=snow.swing
       :image="null"
       :zIndex="10000"
       :resize="true"
       color="#fff"
        />
```

И если загнать объект `snow` в `data`, а после изменять его в `methods`, то все ломается. Причем ошибка выкидывается `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'opacity' of undefine`.

Ощущение, что моя реализация не соответствует дзену реактивности `VueJS`.

### Также возник второй вопрос:

Если я создам `Computed` метод, который возвращает объект `snow`, то я могу сразу запихнуть его в тег `Snowf`?
Аля:

```
<Snowf
           this.get_snow
           :image="null"
           :zIndex="10000"
           :resize="true"
           color="#fff"
            />
```

Провел аналогию с анпакингом из питона в стиле:

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
def lol(a, b):
   print(a+b)

lol(**a)
```

Answer (score -1):

Все проблемы, практически, решились путем создания `Computed` функции

```
snow_props: function () {
                return {
                    swing: this.snow.swing,
                    speed: this.snow.speed,
                    wind: this.snow.wind,
                    amount: this.snow.amount,
                    opacity: this.snow.opacity,
                    size: this.snow.size,
                    color: this.snow.color
                }
            }
```

И путем `v-bind` все `Props` сразу докинулись в тэг `Snowf`:

```
 <Snowf
                v-bind="snow_props"
                :image="null"
                :zIndex="1"
                :resize="true"
        />
```

Однако, при изменении `amount` (количества снежинок) все ломается, но это, я полагаю, уже проблема пакета.

Comment: т. е вы совсем не заметили, что передаёт в атрибуты компонента snowf неверные значения? Нужно :amount="snow.amount". Ошибка на Вашей стороне в синтаксисе

Comment: `:amount="snow.amount"`??? А у меня не так чтоли?

Comment: нет, у Вас :amount=snow.amount без кавычек. Это большая разница.

Comment: @letUser, чтож. Буду знать. Спасибо!